# Git keeps asking for non-existing password

Tags: windows, git, ssh, gitlab

I'm having trouble getting any Git commands to work properly.
I reinstalled everything Git-related to see if it works better, but now I can't even clone a project. Git keeps asking for a password, and there is no password.

```
c:\Users\bls\Git>git clone -v gitlab@svn.faktab.net:pospayclient/api.git
16:14:29.129279 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'clone' '-v' 'gitlab@svn.faktab.net:pospayclient/api.git'
Cloning into 'api'...
16:14:29.199280 run-command.c:335       trace: run_command: 'ssh' 'gitlab@svn.faktab.net' 'git-upload-pack '\''pospayclient/api.git'\'''
gitlab@svn.faktab.net's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
gitlab@svn.faktab.net's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
gitlab@svn.faktab.net's password:
Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I know from experience that when Git asks for a non-existant password, the problem can be

- A) Mismatched SSH key - This key has worked before
- B) Bad project address - I know for certain the address is correct
- C) SSH key has not been added to SSH agent - My colleagues never use the SSH agent, atleast not manually.

Other possible causes?

Comment: 1) turn off password authentication on server or client 2) Post logs from server to investigate the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Somehow the problem was resolved by making a new key